excel macro copy/paste range to next available row
Learning Excel and I'm stuck with not able to run any modifications of this code. In "Q145:AE211" I have data which is changed every time. Every time it's changed I plan to copy it in "Q1:AE1" first and for every next after that skipping one cell for visibility purposes. So if macro is triggered (by button) then first it paste data in "Q1:AE1" then, if button pushed again, and if cells are "busy" next one in "AF1:AS1" and so forth ..
    Range("Q145:AE211").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    If IsEmpty(Range("Q1:AE1")) Then

    Range("Q1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    Range("Q1" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(17).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False


Apart from the glaring issue of you trying to go from Range(Q11048576) - which is 10 million higher than max - upwards, why are you going with bottom to top instead of right to left if you want to move to the right, i.e. Q1:AE1 -> AF1:AT1 (Q to AE is 15 long, AF to AS is only 14) ? Could check which is the most outer column and Offset by 2 to have your "skipping one cell" which would make it Q1:AE1 -> AG1:AU1 if I'm not mistaken. Give "How to avoid using select in vba" a read as well :)

What do you expect from IsEmpty(Range("Q1:AE1"))?

then, if button pushed again Make Excel go to the last non blank COLUMN of row 1. Pasta data there. You can use the macro recorder and adapt the code

With IsEmpty(Range("Q1:AE1")) I meant to check, if Q1:AE1 is empty, if not then first paste it there. And yeah I know the code rises questions, I copied it from other stackoverflow code and tried to play around without even realising its using bottom to top. VBA is new to me and im trying to put it together from sources.

If you want checking if in that range there are on not values, IsEmpty does not do that... Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a variable has been initialized.. In the way you try using it, it will always return False, independent of the range content... It will always ran the second part of the If Statement. So, it does nothing... Please, try the answer I posted, using an array, not involving ClipBoard, which is much faster even for very large ranges.

If I correctly understood your question, please try the next fast way. It will paste after the last column. Not needing format, using an array is the fasted way of pasting:
Sub copyAfterTheLastColumn()
 Dim lastCol As Long, arr
 
 arr = Range("Q145:AE211").value
 lastCol = cells(1, columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column + 1
 
 Cells(1, lastCol).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).value = arr
End Sub


This will place horizontally the sequential results ranges
    Range("Q145:AE211").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    If IsEmpty(Range("Q1:AE1")) Then

    Range("Q1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,2).Select    'changed
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End If

    Application.CutCopyMode = False


It solves it perfectly, just one question -  Offset(0,2) - if I change to Offset(0,15), Excel brokes, I change it to 15 because I need that the next data is copied after 15 row cells, because the data takes overall 14 cells.

If you copy them below each other after a while it will reach the source range. Letters mean columns. As of your source : Q145:AE211 is 15 columns x 67 rows. The End(xlToLeft) find the the far right cell with value in the first row, and select  two cells to the right of it.
